# Enable second monitor from shell

Tags: command-line, xorg, wine, monitors

So... I have two monitors on my Ubuntu machine. And every time I launch some Windows OpenGL application under Wine it turns off the second monitor. And leaves it turned off when the application exits. 
I wonder, is there a shell command which will instantly turn the second monitor on?

Comment: Try the `xrandr` command?

Comment: Any concrete samples?

Comment: Depends a lot on what you have/what you want. I use this on my laptop - `xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --same-as LVDS1`. You can have `--left-of`, `--right-of` etc.

Comment: Ok, I'l try to read man

Comment: @Graeme you can answer question,and I will accept your answer. I read man page and created a link on my desktop which does what I want.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `xrandr` command is the one you are looking for. An example usage is:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --same-as LVDS1
```

You can have `--left-of`, `--right-of`. Run `xrandr` on its own to see the different outputs that are available.

Comment: I'll add that to find out names of outputs one can run `xrandr --current`

Comment: @AleksandrKravets, shouldn't be any different than `xrandr` on its own in most cases. The man page says that this avoids looking for any hardware changes, so I would avoid this unless I have a specific reason to use it.

Comment: You're right, I just didn't try it that way :)

Answer (score 2):

Use xrandr command without args for view your output names and the supported resolutions.

Once you have this informations, you can setup a screen like this (this is an example, there is a lot of others options):

```
**xrandr --output <output> --mode <resolution> --right-of/--left-of <output>**
```

You can also just reactivate your screen with:

```
**xrandr --output <output> --auto**
```

Comment: Sorry, there's no such thing as  `--on` option. But there's `--auto`.